# ios search bar swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a search bar like google map.

In the first view, I want a search bar. When a user click on this, a new view is openning.

Do you know how to create this ?

I have tried to do this but the search bar always display on the same view.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` by using the protocol `UISearchBarDelegate`.